# Source for medium quantities of salts

Tags: reference-request

Where are good sources for medium quantities (10-1000kg) of chemicals, particularly salts?

For quantities <10kg, I know of lots of options from lab suppliers (Sigma Aldrich, Alfa Aesar, etc). These companies generally charge a premium for quality that make bulk purchases unreasonably expensive.

For quantities >1000kg, I know of industrial sources (Univar, BASF, etc) and it seems they have local resellers in most markets. These companies typically have minimum orders of $1000 or so.

I am in the US.

What keywords should I be searching to find a local or online vendor of in between quantities?

Comment: Regarding this hold- wow, for how much time I spend on this site, including reading the rules, I do not understand the rules.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the chemical which you want to order, many salts are used in society and industry for a range of purposes. if it is sodium chloride then I suggest you buy lots of packets of table salt.

A word of warning if you try to purchase medium to large amounts of some salts such as ammonium nitrate then you might be investigated as a possible terrorist. I would rather not give out any tips on what people might be on the lookout for, but if you attempt to buy some substances in bulk with no obvious use then people may report you.

I have to ask why you want ton amounts of chemicals such as salts ?

Comment: Like @Nuclear Chemist said, if you are working for a ligitimate business, then you can ask big companies such as VWR or Fisher Scientific a quote for your chemical. Sometimes, they'd surprise you by how cheap they can get.

Comment: I do indeed want these chemicals for a legitimate business. We are just chemical-industry-adjacent so we don't have relationships with those suppliers. Thanks for the tips.